# Laravel View can't call subfolder views

Tags: view, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm having some error trying to call a view from a subfolder.
First, this thing works

```
Route::get('/', function() { return View::make('sample'); });
```

but when I try to call this inside a folder like this

```
Route::get('/', function() { return View::make('pages.sample'); });
```

it returns me an error like this:

```
[2014-06-08 16:00:43] production.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'View [pages.sample] not found.' in /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php:9076 Stack trace:
0 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(9049): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findInPaths('pages.sample', Array)
1 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(124): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find('pages.sample')
2 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(3225): Illuminate\View\Factory->make('pages.sample')
3 /var/www/app/routes.php(16): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('make', Array)
4 /var/www/app/routes.php(16): Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::make('pages.sample')
5 [internal function]: {closure}()
6 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(5098): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
7 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(4795): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
8 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(4783): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
9 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(706): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
10 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(687): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
11 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(7425): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
12 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(8031): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
13 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(7978): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
14 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(10747): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
15 /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php(648): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
16 /var/www/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
17 {main} [] []
```

I tried reinstalling everything but seems it doesn't work. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your sub folder name is pages ?

Comment: Yes i doubled check everything.

Comment: Maybe you should try `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Yes I did that too. Also cleared cache. I wonder if its the folder permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. The folders and files are not group-owned by "www-data" which causes this error. This usually happens when you are using LAMP. I hope this helps anyone with this kind of problem. For anyone wonders what is the command:

```
sudo chgrp -R  www-data /var/www/app/views/*
```

Answer (score 0):

When a new folder is created manually inside views by commandline, "Others" are not given "x" permission, which is required by www-data to execute folder(go inside and see).
Just ensure that

```
chmod +x <folder_name>
```

owner and group can remain root:root

(Laravel Version:8.83.10, in Debian 11)